# Unable to get all C# class files of dll into nunit

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have added a new class file into the project. And compiled it. I got a successful build.
 But when i am trying to run the same dll into NUnit i am not getting the newly added class file in NUnit.

Ho to get this newly added class file into the NUnit? I am running the test in NUnit with selenium webdriver. using NUnit version 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is that you may have not added the `[Test]` attribute on the class name.

Answer (score 0):

[Nunit documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5.9) says the following regarding classes that are picked up for testing:

> TestFixtureAttribute (NUnit 2.0 / 2.5)
>
> This is the attribute that marks a class that contains tests and,
>   optionally, setup or teardown methods. NUnit 2.5 introduces
>   parameterized and generic test fixtures - see below.
>
> Most restrictions on a class that is used as a test fixture have now
>   been eliminated. As of NUnit 2.5.3, a test fixture class:
>
> - May be public, protected, private or internal.
> - May be a static class in .NET 2.0 or later.
> - May be generic, so long as any type parameters are provided or can be inferred from the actual arguments.
> - May not be abstract - although the attribute may be applied to an abstract class intended to serve as a base class for test fixtures.
> - If no arguments are provided with the TestFixtureAttribute, the class must have a default constructor.
> - If arguments are provided, they must match one of the constructors.
>
> **If any of these restrictions are violated, the class is not runnable
>   as a test and will display as an error.**
>
> It is advisable that the constructor not have any side effects, since
>   NUnit may construct the object multiple times in the course of a
>   session.
>
> **Beginning with NUnit 2.5, the TestFixture attribute is optional for
>   non-parameterized, non-generic fixtures**. So long as the class contains
>   at least one method marked with the Test, TestCase or TestCaseSource
>   attribute, it will be treated as a test fixture.

(emphasis mine)

I'd advise going through the list to check whether any of these restrictions are violated. If not, your nunit runner may not be pointing at the latest version of your assembly, but this is heavily setup-dependent so it's harder to troubleshoot the problem.